# Salvar dados através de POST no banco com Vraptor

Tags: java-ee, rest, restful, vraptor

Tenho dois métodos em meu `Controller`, um que lista todos os dados do banco e um método para salvar dados no banco. Já consigo listar todos os dados quando acesso a `URI` porém quando tento salvar da esse erro:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the
>   response has been committed   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:494)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:138)
>     at
>   br.com.caelum.vraptor.http.VRaptorResponse.sendRedirect(VRaptorResponse.java:48)
>     at
>   br.com.caelum.vraptor.view.DefaultLogicResult$2.intercept(DefaultLogicResult.java:151)
>     at
>   br.com.caelum.vraptor.proxy.JavassistProxifier$MethodInvocationAdapter.invoke(JavassistProxifier.java:106)
>     at
>   com.vraptor.controller.EmpresaController_$$_jvst52d_1.listAll(EmpresaController_$$_jvst52d_1.java)
>     at
>   com.vraptor.controller.EmpresaController.salvar(EmpresaController.java:42)

Qual a causa desse erro e como posso resolve-lo?

OBS: quando testo o POST ele tenta fazer a inserção no banco, porém só a chave primária que é auto incremento é salva.

---

**Controller**:

```
@Controller
@Path("/empresa")
public class EmpresaController {

    @Inject
    private Result result;
    @Inject
    private EmpresaDAO empresaDAO;

    @Get
    @Path("/list")
    public void listAll() {
        result.use(Results.json())
        .withoutRoot()
        .from(empresaDAO.listar())
        .serialize();
    }

    @Post
    @Path(value = { "/", "" })
    @Consumes(value = "application/json", options = WithoutRoot.class)
    public void salvar(Empresa empresa) {
        empresaDAO.salvar(empresa);
        result.redirectTo(this).listAll(); // Essa é a linha 42 que está lançando a exception
    }

}
```

**DAO:**

```
public void salvar(Empresa empresa) {
        Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transacao = null;
        try {
            transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
            sessao.save(empresa);
            transacao.commit();

        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            sessao.close();

        }
    }
```

Estou usando o complemento `RESTClient` do Firefox para fazer os testes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não pode fazer isso:

```
result.redirectTo(this).listAll()
```

O ciclo de vida de um *Controller* não permite que você redirecione outra requisição para ele. Poderia causar *loops* infinitos de cabeçalhos de requisição.

O correto é definir `EmpresaController.class`, que criará uma requisição com um *Controller* novo:

```
result.redirectTo(EmpresaController.class).listAll()
```

---

**EDIT**

Melhor usar outro plugin pra testar. [Eu uso este](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Cigano.